# How can i publish audio by web socket

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am developing an application which publish audio stream from  mic through web sockets i am not able to play web socket response in audio control or can anyone tell how to play audio buffer in audio control please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following code to play the sounds created with a software-synth.
The samples need to be in the range [-1.0 .. 1.0]. You should initialize `context` in the page init function.

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();

function playSound(buffer, freq, vol)   // buffer, sampleRate, 0-100
{
    var mBuffer = context.createBuffer(1, buffer.length, freq);

    var dataBuffer = mBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    var soundBuffer = buffer;
    var i, n = buffer.length;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        dataBuffer[i] = soundBuffer[i];

    var node = context.createBufferSource();
    node.buffer = mBuffer;
    node.gain.value = 0.5 * vol/100.0;
    node.connect(context.destination);
    node.noteOn(0);
}
```

Comment: Its not works for me because i want to send mic audio to websoket or convert mic audio in byte

Comment: Well, that unfortunately, is another issue. Cant help you there mate. The code above will play an audio buffer. If the values you have are bytes, the value (typically) ranges from [-128..127] You need to convert these values to floating point ones first. E.g `(((byteVal+128) / 255.0)*2) - 1.0`, or more simply: `((byteVal+128)/128.0) - 1.0` Google searches for `webKitAudioContext` should yield some suitable results for you.